# SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlcommand

When should I use `Parameters. Add/AddWithValue`?
In the following MSDN example they use `Parameters.Add` for `int` and `Parameters.AddWithValue` for `string`

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);
```

What is the best to use for `datetime`

Comment: [`cmd.Parameters.Add` is deprecated now. Instead use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29554589/3936696)

Comment: @RahulNikate As stated by Bacon Bits below, "cmd.Parameters.Add(String, SqlDbType) is not deprecated. Only cmd.Parameters.Add(String, Object) is deprecated (now obsolete)."

Comment: In fact, the recent trend among SQL experts (search relevant keywords for articles) seems to favor using Add(String, SqlDBType) and abandoning AddWithValue due to inefficiency caused by datatype ambiguity. (Yeah, the question is ancient...but I'm here now!)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `Add` if you want to make all explicit with a little bit more work. Use `AddWithValue` if you are lazy. `AddWithValue` will derive the type of the parameter of its value, so ensure that it's the correct type. You should, for example, parse a `string` to `int` if that is the correct type.

There is one reason to avoid `Add`: if your parameter type is `int` you must be careful with the [overload that takes the parameter-name and an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since then [another overload is chosen with the `SqlDbType`-enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (method overload is even `obsolete` now):

> Use caution when you are using this overload of the
>   `SqlParameterCollection.Add` method to specify integer parameter values.
>   Because this overload takes a value of type Object, you must convert
>   the integral value to an Object type when the value is zero
>   ... If you do not perform this conversion, the
>   compiler assumes that you are trying to call the
>   `SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, SqlDbType)` overload.

Comment: [`cmd.Parameters.Add` is deprecated now. Instead use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29554589/3936696)

Comment: @RahulNikate: `AddWithValue` is also not the best way since it infers the type of the parameter from the paramater value. This often leads to bad execution plans or incorrect conversions. It also doesn't validate the parameter in the first place(f.e. type if `Datetime` but you pass a `String`). Only `Add(String parameterName, Object value)`  is deprecated all other overloads of `Add` not. I prefer the one that takes the parameter-name and the `SqlDbType`(consider to specify the size if string-type).

Comment: `AddWithValue` just avoids the problem mentioned in my answer and has the same functionality as `Add(string, object)`.

Comment: I disagree with Add being better than AddWithValue -- they can both make mistakes -- so use which ever one is simpler.  Add can be used to set up your parameters ahead of time so that you only need to specify the object.  Plus, this `Parameters.Add("@BEGDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate`.  Almost as short as AddWithValue.

Comment: Note that [`cmd.Parameters.Add(String, SqlDbType)` is not deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx).  Only [`cmd.Parameters.Add(String, Object)` is deprecated (now obsolete)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).