# Taking long time to fill data table from data adapter C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have created a method to get a datatable, it was taking more than a minute for this line of code

```
da.Fill(dt)
```

but in SQL Server, with the same parameters, the procedure will execute with in  a second:

```
protected DataTable RetrieveDataTable(string staffId, string 
    DtFrom, string DtTo, string Stm, string JrId,int ActiveFlag)
{
    dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"]);
    Conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Proc_QCArticleDetails", Conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StaffId", staffId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FrmDt", DtFrom));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ToDt", DtTo));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ActiveFlag", ActiveFlag));

        try
        {
            int jrid = Convert.ToInt32(JrId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@journalId", JrId));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Statement", Stm));
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 250;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);     // taking a long time to run here
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        Conn.Close();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to include `Proc_QCArticleDetails`. Also please update it to include how many records are typically returned.

Comment: Yuck! Empty catch and try-catch to parse string to int, use `int.TryParse`. Also, use the `using`-statement for everything that implements `IDisposable` like the `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Post the query. I'm pretty sure you *don't* execute the same query in SSMS even if you think you do. For example `dtFrom`, `dtoTo` look like dates but have  a *string* type. Are you *sure* that string is correctly parsed? Are you comparing those strings with date fields or string fields? If strings, you have a serious bug and probably return the wrong data. Pass *properly typed parameters*.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at below discussion.
[Adapter.Fill takes long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186380/adapter-fill-takes-long)

According to this post there might be issue because of method of adding parameters.
Also use `Using` and `int.TryParse` as suggested in comment.

Comment: Don't post an answer to point out a duplciate, flag the question as a duplicate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Even though procedure execute with in second it takes long time to fill data table (da.fill(dt)),I Not able to find exact Issue but i resolved  by 
removing  where condition in stored procedure and filter data table in C# using data view Finally issue was resolved for me.