# C# boolean needs converted to bit for SQL Server so instead of True it needs to be 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a C# property which is of data type `bool` and when it gets set, it becomes a `True` or `False`.

However I need for it to match up with a SQL Server table column of type `bit` so that it is saved as a 1 or 0.

SQL Server column:

```
StormOut bit
```

C# property

```
public bool StormOut { get; set; }
```

C# SQL statement:

```
string querystring = "UPDATE tblSignOnOff SET StormOut = " + storm.StormOut + " WHERE id = 1902";
```

Otherwise currently the SQL statement in C# is

```
UPDATE tblSignOnOff 
SET StormOut = True 
WHERE id = 1902
```

Which results in an error:

> Invalid column name 'True'.

Comment: you can try `Parameters.AddWithValue` to make a parameterized query which probably might help yop

Answer (score 6):

You have missed single quotes. Change like this:

```
string querystring = "UPDATE tblSignOnOff SET StormOut = '" + storm.StormOut + "' WHERE id = 1902";
```

**But an important note:** You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) like below. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
string querystring = "UPDATE tblSignOnOff SET StormOut = @StormOut WHERE id = @id";
yourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1902);
yourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StormOut", storm.StormOut);
```

Comment: Ok cool,  I thought I was going to have to do "Convert.ToInt16 your Boolean value. That will make true/false, 0 or 1 "

Comment: Yes to: "use parameterized queries"! Don't ever build sql statements by simply concatenating strings/values.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters and avoid string concatenation

```
string Command = "UPDATE tblSignOnOff SET StormOut @StormOut WHERE id = @id";
using (SqlConnection mConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1902); // TODO set this value dynamically
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StormOut", storm.StormOut);

        int RowsAffected = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is difference from Add vs AddWithValue  ?

Comment: I'd personally avoid `AddWithValue`, specify the type directly and use the `Value` property, but this is at least better than the original code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue

Comment: @JonSkeet   I don't follow you.  use Value property ?  example?

Comment: @Jon is this just a personal thing or are there good reasons to avoid `AddWithValue`

Comment: @Byyo: It avoids using inferences you don't want. See http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ for example.

Comment: @MillRunner: `command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID;`

Answer (score -1):

Further modifying the answer from @S.Akbari with his suggestion for parameterized queries;

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblSignOnOff SET StormOut = @StormOut WHERE id = @id";    
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StormOut", storm.StormOut);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1902);
```

Comment: that was rude copy & paste

Comment: @Byyo If you really think that I copy paste your answer, tell me, I'll remove mine..

Answer (score -1):

```
int bitValue = booleanVar == true? 1: 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].