# C# Stored Procedure function expects parameter '@id' which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

[image]

I'm getting this error and although I know it's been asked many many times, I tried to research my error and still nothing's work.

Is there any error to my code ? I hope someone would be able to help in this matter. I've been stuck on this for a week. I tried differnt opinions of other developer but still nothing solves.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddProduct

@ID int,
@Image varbinary(max),
@Supplier varchar(50),
@Codeitem varchar(50),
@Itemdescription varchar(50),   
@Date varchar(50),
@Quantity varchar(50),
@Unitcost varchar(50),
@ADD nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
        IF @ADD = 'Insert'
INSERT INTO  dbo.employee_product
(
Image,
Supplier,
Codeitem,
Itemdescription,
Date,
Quantity,
Unitcost    
)
VALUES
(
@Image,
@Supplier,
@Codeitem,
@Itemdescription,
@Date,
@Quantity,
@Unitcost   
)

END
```

**My Code:**

```
        byte[] image = null;
        var stream = new FileStream(this.txt_path.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var read = new BinaryReader(stream);
        image = read.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbox_supplier.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_code.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_item.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_quantity.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_cost.Text))
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("AddProduct", con);
                selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", "Insert");
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",SqlDbType.Int ).Value = 0;
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbox_supplier.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbox_supplier.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codeitem", txt_code.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemdescription", txt_item.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txt_date.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_quantity.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unitcost", txt_cost.Text.Trim());
                selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Added successfully", "SIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                _view._product();

            }

        }
```

Comment: You are adding `@Supplier` two times.

Comment: Already remove it but still getting that error

Comment: Why does the stored procedure even take the `@ID` parameter? It is not used.

Comment: You mean , i need to insert it too ?

Comment: @Miracle are you asking me? My guess is no, you do not have to insert it but I don't know your table definition. I'm just saying you do not use the parameter so why is it there?

Comment: You should read this. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type You have a number of datatypes that are seem like a poor choice here.

Comment: Another thing to try is the square brackets around the Date field. Date is a reserved keyword and you should always put square brackets around these words (albeit the error message should be "Syntax error")

Comment: As @SeanLange says. You have passed all strings even for fields that seems to expect Dates or Numeric values. AddWithValue is famous to wreak havoc in this context [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Steve but since they are using stored procs the AddWithValue doesn't have to guess the types. I still prefer to be explicit though. :)

Comment: @Miracle thank you for posting the code. It helps because we can see it is still wrong. Putting the SqlDbType in the second parameter is not right when using AddWithValue. Do it like Philip showed you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: @Miracle why on earth you showed us a piece of code that has nothing to do with the image posted. In that image there is no parameter added to the DataAdapter SelectCommand.

Comment: @Steve Sorry about that

Comment: But the error happens as showed in the previous image now removed, not in the code posted. This makes all this discussion useless. This is the link to the original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXKfL.png

Answer (score 3):

Reading an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110078/395675) to another question it states:

> Use caution when you are using this overload of the SqlParameterCollection.Add method to 
>   specify integer parameter values. Because this overload takes a value of type Object, 
>   you must convert the integral value to an Object type when the value is zero, as the 
>   following C# example demonstrates.

```
parameters.Add("@pname", Convert.ToInt32(0));
```

> If you do not perform this conversion, the compiler assumes that you are trying to call 
>   the SqlParameterCollection.Add (string, SqlDbType) overload.

This is most likely your issue.

Comment: But i already assign the data type as int and already incremented it. Still need to convert it as integer ?

Comment: Not sure if AddWithValue has the same problem. In any case better to call _Add(name, type).Value = 0;_

Comment: Only one way to find out.

Comment: I tried your answer but it didn't work

Comment: @Miracle can you edit your question to show your updated code so we know exactly what you tried?

Comment: Try assigning the zero to an `int` variable and passing that to your `AddWithValue` call. .NET may be seeing the zero as fitting a smaller integral type.

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't think i need to rephrase my question sir , because my error is still that

Comment: @Miracle just your code if it is different than what you originally posted.

Comment: @Crowcoder   selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",SqlDbType.Int ).Value = 0; i change it but still getting this error

Comment: @Miracle That is wrong. Change the method name to `Add` not `AddWithValue`

Comment: sorry about that. already correct it but still nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You're adding ten parameters in your C# code here:

```
var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("AddProduct", con);
selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", "Insert");
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",0);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbox_supplier.Text);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbox_supplier.Text.Trim()); // <== duplicate?
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codeitem", txt_code.Text.Trim());
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemdescription", txt_item.Text.Trim());
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txt_date.Text.Trim());
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_quantity.Text.Trim());
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unitcost", txt_cost.Text.Trim());
```

But your procedure only takes 9 parameters, I think you might have duplicated the Supplier parameter?

Comment: Already remove it sir, sorry for that but still getting error

Comment: can you run SQL Profiler trace to see what is actually being sent to the server?

Comment: First time heard of it