# How to pass the parameter in sqlParam

Tags: c#, sql

how to pass a parameter to sqlParam

```
_id=23
SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand("select X from TAB where ID= @id", new SqlParam("id", K_{0}), _id)).ExecScalar<int>();
```

I have a variable that should be need to pass in SqlParam. parameters `id="K_23"` or `"K_3131"`. now sql does't see this parameter.
How it correctly make!?

Comment: What do you want to pass to the command? 23? This would be `new SqlParam("id", 23)` ... what is K_23 oder K_3131? Maybe you can elaborate your question.

Comment: its my parameter like new SqlParam("id", K_23), where K_ = constant and 23 value (variable value which I find in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, I think you are looking for this:

```
private int _id = 23
// ...
var idParam = new SqlParam("id", string.Format("K_{0}", _id))
SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand("... where ID=@id", idParam).ExecScalar<int>();
```

`string.Format("K_{0}", _id)` creates the string "K_23". Another way in the newer C# versions would be `$"K_{_id}"`.

`new SqlParam("id", "K_23")` creates a string parameter with the value "K_23".

Your command then filters by `ID='K_23'`.

*Is that what you are trying to achive? Or is K_23 a field in your database and you want to check if the field ID has the same value as the field K_23?*

Answer (score 1):

The pattern generally runs more like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @val", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", 123);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new...);
```

But please read these:

[SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

And in particular these, if you're thinking of using AddWithValue heavily:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Actually, for the most part you shouldn't really be writing code like this at all any more for the simple stuff* - there are plenty of good data access libraries/methodologies (EF, nHibernate, Dapper, DataTables) that mean that slinging SQL-inside-strings into your event handlers etc is just not necessary and is primitive/unproductive. Noone spends time writing code to raw lines on screen to represent a button; they just add a Button to the page/form. There's no need to get that low level with databases either; use a data access framework

*`select blah from blah where blah` is undeniably simple stuff. Everyone should be handing those kinds of queries off to an ORM library, and i'm completely appalled that use of `SqlCommand/DataReader` etc is still taught/advocated for this level of query complexity