# How to pass a SQL command in C# to check record where date is equal to an input date from user

Tags: c#

I want to pass a SQL command so that I check for a record in the database which has same date as an input date by the user.

I have a table `Rooms` with columns

```
RoomID (PK)
StudentID (FK)
RoomType 
Date 
StartingTime
Duration
FinishingTime
```

I want to pass the SQL command to check the date a user will input in a `dateTimePicker` to the values in the Date column. I also want to check if the input `roomtype` is same as values in the `RoomType` column, so that if it is the same `roomtype` and date, then the code checks whether the times are not in conflict.

```
public bool reserveRoom() //function for reserving a room
{
    bool allow = true;
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Rooms (StudentID, RoomType, Date, StartingTime, DurationInHour, FinishingTime) values (@studentid, @roomtype, @date, @startingtime, @duration, @finishingtime)", con);

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select StudentID from Students where TPEmail = '" + StudentEmail + "'", con);

    SqlDataReader rd = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    int id = 0;

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        id = rd.GetInt32(0);
    }

    rd.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(Date.Date.ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select StartingTime from Rooms where RoomType = '" + RoomType + "' and Date = '" + Date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'", con) ;

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Rooms where RoomType = '" + RoomType + "'" + " and Date ='" + Date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'", con);

    int count = Int32.Parse(cmd4.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

    String[] startingTime = new string[count];
    //int ident = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (rd2.Read())
    {
        startingTime[index] = rd2.GetTimeSpan(0).ToString();
        index += 1;
    }

    rd.Close();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomtype", RoomType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Date.Date);

    string timeStart = (Time1 + ":" + Time2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startingtime", TimeSpan.Parse(timeStart));

    double doubleDuration = Int32.Parse(DurationHour) + ((Double.Parse(DurationMinute)) / 60);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", doubleDuration);

    int hour = Int32.Parse(Time1) + Int32.Parse(DurationHour);
    int min = Int32.Parse(Time2) + Int32.Parse(DurationMinute);

    if (min >= 60)
    {
        min -= 60;
        hour += 1;
    }

    string timeFinish = (hour + ":" + min);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finishingtime", TimeSpan.Parse(timeFinish));

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (i != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reservation successful.");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to reserve");

    foreach (string item in startingTime)
    {
        TimeSpan timeItem = TimeSpan.Parse(item);

        if (Int32.Parse((timeItem - TimeSpan.Parse(timeFinish)).ToString()) >= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Accept");
        }
    }

    con.Close();
    return allow;
}
```

Can someone help me please?

[image]

Help please

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Your `SqlCommand` should **ALL** be like the first one - properly **parametrized**!

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) | [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: Also, this `SqlDataReader rd2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();` really goes against the *Principle of Least Surprise" - if you have `cmd`, `cmd2`, `cmd3` and `cmd4` - name your readers the same! Don't use **rd2** for **cmd3** - you're just **asking** for confusion later on! And of course - it would be **much better** to use a **descriptive** name rather than just `cmd2`, `cmd3` etc .....

Comment: What do you mean by parametrized queries?

Comment: Issues with your current code: SQL injection, instead you should use parameters. You are using a cached connection, instead create the connection when you need it. Dispose connection, command and reader objects with `using` blocks. You could run all of this logic in a single SQL batch or procedure, there is no need to query data back to the application only to pass it back again. `ExecuteScalar()` can return an actual `int` if that is what the query is returning, don't mess about with `ToString` and `Parse` just cast it `(int)`. Don't mess about parsing `TimeSpan`, just use addition ......

Comment: ..... and subtraction of actual integers. Don't block the thread with `MessageBox` while the connection is open. Don't use `AddWithValue`, specify parameter type and length explicitly. A `datetime` is not a `TimeSpan`. You are always returning `true` as you never set `allow`.