# SQLite syntax error inside of command: 'SQL logic error near "=": syntax error'

Tags: c#, sqlite

I keep getting the exception

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
> near "=": syntax error'

and I have no idea why or whats causing it :(

my code is as follows

```
SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = StuTchInfo.db");
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(c);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *" +
    "FROM tblTeachers" +
   $"WHERE teacherID = '{idField.Text.ToString()}'";
c.Open();
SQLiteDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//code processing data from data reader
```

and the exception is thrown on the last line. `idField.Text` is a string value and I have already tried using `idField.Text.ToString()` but it still throws the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no point calling ToString on a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) and [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: Besides not using string concatenation and bad formatting/indentation, here it is a typo: a space is missing before WHERE, thus write for example `$" WHERE ..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add space.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM tblTeachers " +
    $"WHERE teacherID = '{idField.Text.ToString()}'";
```

Comment: oh wow that was really it idk how i forgot string concatenation doesn't automatically put a space

Comment: Sql won't care about `SELECT *FROM`, btw

Comment: @CaiusJard Good to know, but anyway it would be good to have this space for better readability.

Comment: Verbatim string is much easier, preface with `@`, then you can use newlines

Answer (score 4):

Your string concatenation is causing an sql that contains `tblTeachersWHERE`

If you want to keep a multi line format for readability, you can ditch the string concat by using an `@string`

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
  SELECT *
  FROM tblTeachers
  WHERE teacherID = @name";

//you'll need this too; gives a value to the above parameter
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", idField.Text);
```

You can also investigate Resources facility (right click on project name and choose Properties, then Resources on the left, and "click there" if your project doesnt have one); it allows you to write long strings like huge SQLs and not clutter your code with them. Code would be like:

```
cmd.CommandText = Properties.Resources.SelectFromTeachersWhereNameIs;
```

and your designer for the Resources be like:

[image]

---

As a side note, investigate how to parametrize your queries (I did it above with @name), because even if you fix  this your code will explode again as soon as someone enters a `'` into the textbox, [or worse](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some spaces in your string. Also, you can have `one-liner` code by using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

```
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM tblTeachers WHERE teacherID = '{idField.Text.ToString()}'";
```

Comment: I'll probably try doing this from now on at least until i get more used to SQL commands considering I managed to forget string concatenation doesn't automatically add spaces