# C# : Why is the value of empno between single quotes even though the empno is defined as an integer?

Tags: c#

```
string sql = "select * from e where empno= ' " + datagridview.currentrow.cells(0).value.tostring() + " ' ";
```

Why is the value of `empno` between single quotes even though the `empno` is defined as an integer?

Comment: Why do you ask to us? I am sure that none here has put that quotes there

Comment: Good question, it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Please don't create SQL statements by concatenating values, please learn how to use sql parameters.

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) • [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May i make a suggestion to make your code easier to read.
When working with string formatting, use interpolation rather than the '+' operator.

String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted string.

Example :

```
// Replace this line
string sql = "select * from e where empno= ' " + datagridview.currentrow.cells(0).value.tostring() + " ' "; 

// By this one
string sql = $"select * from e where empno='{datagridview.currentrow.cells(0).value.tostring()}'";
```

Documentation : [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Do not encourage SQL injection.