# How to select data from MariaDB in C# with variable value in where condition

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, mariadb

I want to know how to select data from MariaDB in C# with variable value in where condition. Please see my code, I am getting this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1'

Please correct me with my code if I am wrong.

Here is my code

```
var2 = Forms.frmLogin.var1;
connection2.Open();
string selectQuery = "Select Role from car_dealer.users where email = "+var2+" ";
command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection2);
mdr = command.ExecuteReader();
if (mdr.Read())
{
    var3 = mdr.GetString("Role");
}

//lblUsername.Text = var2;
connection2.Close();
MessageBox.Show(var3);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) • [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: You forgot quotes in case of email is a string/text/varchar column... `'" + var2 + "'` but don't do that and use SQL Parameters.

Comment: Use parameters to prevent SQLi and *syntax* issues.

Answer (score -2):

Could you change the query with this?

```
string selectQuery = "Select Role from car_dealer.users  where email = '"+var2+"' ";
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not do this, use parameters.

Comment: I'm just trying to fix the following code. But you are right. It's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to wrap the email address within quotes.

You can use C# string interpolation syntax rather than concatenating strings.

```
string selectQuery = $"Select Role from car_dealer.users where email = '{var2}'";
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not do this, use parameters.