# How to edit a record in an access database - visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to edit a specific record in an access database but I keep on getting errors

this is the database I want to edit:
[Access database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehe2L.png)

these are flashcards that the user has created and stored in an access database. What I want is that the user is able to edit the difficulty so it appears more/less often

This is the module:

```
Module Module1
Public Function runSQL(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=flashcard login.accdb") 'Establishes connection to database
    Dim dt As New DataTable 'Stores database in table called dt
    Dim dataadapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    connection.Open() 'Opens connection
    dataadapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection)
    dt.Clear() 'Clears datatable
    dataadapter.Fill(dt) 'Fills datatable
    connection.Close()
    Return dt
End Function
End Module
```

And here is the button that the user can press to edit the database:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "UPDATE flashcards set difficulty = '" & TxtDifficulty.Text
    runSQL(sql)
End Sub
```

The difficulty column in the database should be able to be edited by the user through the value they entered in txtDifficulty.text

Comment: What are the errors and why is there a single apostrophe in the UPDATE statement?

Comment: Its says its a syntax error and I'm probably wrong but isn't that the way you edit a database?

Comment: What would be an easier way to edit a record inside a database?

Comment: The syntax error appears to be the single apostrophe, remove the apostrophe. Also, did you intend to set difficulty for all row? If not you need a WHERE condition.

Comment: Ah yeah removing the apostrophe removes the syntax problem so thank you! But it changes the whole column to that difficulty. I'm guessing that I am going to need a where statement but the problem I have is that the user can create as much flashcards as they want so how would I write the where statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to hear I found the problem with the apostrophe.

> I am going to need a where statement but the problem I have is that the user can create as much flashcards as they want so how would I write the where statement?

An INSERT statement does not have a WHERE clause but an UPDATE does and is usually by a primary key.

Look at how I [add a new record](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/blob/master/AddingMultipleRecords/Classes/DataOperations.vb) ignoring mHasException and specifically using parameters. In this case a List is used but with little effort an array of DataRow can be passed instead.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/blob/master/BackendBlobs/DataOperations.vb#L41:L66) for updating a record with a DataRow.

To get other code samples for ms-access see the following [repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases).

In closing, in the above repository I don't get into all possibilities yet there should be enough there to get you going. And when reviewing code I flip between Add for adding a parameter and AddWithValue while Add is the recommend way but both are shown to see differences. see also [Add vs AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue).

Comment: Thank you for responding, When updating a record I received no error but the database never actually updated.

Comment: If the database is shown as a item in Solution Explorer then check `Copy to Output Directory` which by default is copy always, change to copy if newer then see if you see updates. See [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx)