# Getting values from a database using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure for getting last row value of a `UserId`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_LoginStatusQ]  
    @UserId int
AS   
BEGIN  
   SELECT MAX(UserTimeId), LoginStatus 
   FROM UserTime 
   WHERE UserId = @UserId 
   GROUP BY UserId, LoginStatus, Day, HoursWorked, Date, CheckIn,UserTimeId 
END
```

In C#, I want to get  the value of LoginStatus. How to do I do this?

I tried:

```
public void GetLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   db.get_LoginStatusQ(Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"])));

   if( LoginStatus ='In') // How do I get the field LoginStatus from the database?
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: You should try writing some code to actually connect to and query your database.  It doesn't look like you have any code that attempts to do that.

Comment: you are right. I am novice and do not know how to implement(code) this. How to get LoginStatus in If clause?

Comment: A quick search yields quite a few results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp, https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+execute+stored+procedure&oq=c%23+execute+sto&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i58j0l3.2605j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the net that teach you basic coding. StackOverflow isn't meant for that.

Comment: have you looked up how to create and or use Parameterized query's along with Sql.DataClient you need to do a little more coding to get the results you're seeking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your C# code try something like this make sure that in your using you have the following
you can change the declaration of the Method signature to Private if you do not have a DAL Class set up of your own.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public static DataSet GetLogin(Int32 userId)
    {
       DataSet logStatusDs = new DataSet();
        //load the List one time to be used thru out the intire application
        var ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_LoginStatusQ", connStr))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(logStatusDs);
            }
        }
        return logStatusDs;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How get LoginStatus from logStatusDs ? Ex : if(logStatusDs='In')

Comment: if you need to change your query to something like `M Ali` had stated and then in your return DataSet `logStatusDs` you would have that field so something like `var logStatus = logStatusDs.Tables[0]["LoginStatus"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure needs some fixing see below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_LoginStatusQ]  
@UserId int
AS   
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 UserTimeId, LoginStatus 
    FROM UserTime 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId 
    ORDER BY UserTimeId DESC
END
```