# c# too many arguments specified in a procedure or a function

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure to check whether the username and password exists in the database and return the results accordingly

This is the stored procedure

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[checkuser]
 @userid varchar(20),
 @password varchar(20),
 @ReturnVal varchar(50) output
 As 
 Begin
 if exists(select userid from users where userid=@userid)
 set @ReturnVal='Logged in Successfully'
 else
 set @ReturnVal='Login Failed'
 end
```

and this is my c# code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
      "File Name=E:\\Vivek\\License Manager\\License Manager\\login.udl");

    try
    {  
        conn.Open();               
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("checkuser",conn);              
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                
        OleDbParameter p1=new OleDbParameter("userid",username.Text); 
        OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter("password",password.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);                
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);                
        var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("ReturnVal",OleDbType.Integer);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

I am new to c#.I want to check whether the username exists from the database.But when I execute the code I get an error saying "too many arguments specified in a procedure or a function ".

Can anyone tell me where am I making a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about `OleDb` but in Sql, you'll have to use `@` prefix for the parameters. I.e `new OleDbParameter("@userid",username.Text);`

Comment: Declare your return value as an [output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx) parameter in the stored procedure, or don't add the `ReturnVal` to the parameters.

Comment: I guess `ReturnVal` should be `@ReturnValue`

Comment: @Yuriy Thanks for the reply.Can you give me a code snippet in c# to get the value from the stored procedure?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I tried adding @ but still showing the same error

Comment: @user2614235 I posted Answer can you try that

Comment: Use `@` prefix for all parameters and change the `ReturnVal` to `@ReturnValue`. Did you tried all of them?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes buddy

Comment: @user2614235 again you forgot to add `@` before parameters in c# code and and change to this `var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal",OleDbType.VarChar,20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedure never returns a value.You have to use a output parameter in stored procedure.

Changes in SP as shown here:

```
create proc checkuser
    @userid varchar(20),
    @password varchar(20)
    @result int output
As 
Begin
   if exists(select userid from users where userid=@userid)
      set @result = 0
   else
      set @result = 1
   end
```

and in C# code:

```
 SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("result", SqlDbType.Int);
  returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
  int id = (int) returnParameter.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to display the return parameter.Eg if my database sends a message in the form of return parameter "Login does not exist"
how to display that message in c#
I hope my doubt is clear

Comment: @Neel I think It should  `@result int output` instead of `@result output int `

Comment: you can take "varchar(50)"  instead of "int" in above code @user2614235

Comment: @Neel it is throwing error converting varchar to string

Comment: u need to convert like  string id = (string) returnParameter.Value;  @user2614235

Comment: it would be better if u update ur question @user2614235

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62502/discussion-between-user2614235-and-neel).

Comment: sorry cant use chat from office @user2614235

Comment: var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal",OleDbType.VarChar,50)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

Replace Your Code with Followings Changes

```
 OleDbParameter p1=new OleDbParameter("@userid",username.Text);


OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter("@password",password.Text);

var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal",OleDbType.Integer);

returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 int Result= Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
```

In the Procedure

```
create proc checkuser
 @userid varchar(20),
 @password varchar(20),
@ReturnVal int output

 As 
 Begin
 if exists(select userid from users where userid=@userid)
 set @ReturnVal= 0
 else

 set @ReturnVal= 1
 end
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but the options shown here 

int Result= Convert.ToInt(returnParameter.Value); is int16 and not int

Comment: Stored procedure throwing errors

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure checkuser, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@ReturnVal'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure checkuser, Line 8
Must declare the scalar variable "@ReturnVal".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure checkuser, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@ReturnVal".

Comment: @user2614235 Its working Fine For me did you copy paste that stored procedure??

Comment: Hey My application does not proceed further when I click the login button :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-Server,Use Sql data base connection and command

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)