# How to call stored procedure from Oracle using PetaPoco

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, petapoco

I have stored procedure in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (p_param1 INTEGER, p_param2 CHAR, p_param3 INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
... 
END;
```

and I call it in Oracle SQL Developer using this statement:

```
EXECUTE proc1(2013, 1, 3);
```

I try to call it in C# from Visual Studio but it doesn't works

```
_db.Execute("EXEC proc1 (2013, 1, 3)");
```

How can I properly call it in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? Any exception or error message you get?

Comment: It throws this exception:
Additional information: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Second parameter is of type `CHAR`. Did you try `_db.Execute("EXEC proc1 (2013, '1', 3)");`?

Comment: of course, I'm triing it too, but it throws the same exception...

Comment: Did you check any of, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: I think, this is no problem with parameters... I try to create procedure without parameters, for example proc2. When I call it in Oracle Sql Developer using 'EXECUTE proc2;' it works, but in visual studio doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC` is a command of SQL*Plus. Try to use command without `EXEC` or in anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
_db.Execute("proc1 (2013, 1, 3)");
```

or

```
_db.Execute("begin proc1 (2013, 1, 3); end;");
```

Also, in this case, `1` could be converted to CHAR automatically, and in other cases you need to use quotes `''`:

```
_db.Execute("begin proc1 (2013, 'abc', 3); end;");
```

Comment: I'm trying your first statement too and it throws the same exception:  invalid SQL statement. I don't know why..?

But second and third way are working both.

Thanks.

Comment: this saved my butt. i had tried over 30 different ways to get this to work until I landed here. thank you kindly sir.