# Is there any danger or disadvantage in omitting the CommandType in a SQLCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have this code that's working fine:

```
        SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection("SERVER=PROSQL05;DATABASE=platypusdata;UID=duckbill;PWD=poisonToe42;Connection Timeout=0");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        String dateBegin = GetYYYYMMDD(monthBegin, beginYear, true);
        String dateEnd = GetYYYYMMDD(monthEnd, endYear, false);
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Exec sp_ViewProductUsage_MappingRS '{0}', '{1}', '{2}'", mammal, dateBegin, dateEnd);
```

...but I wonder if adding the SqlCommand's CommandType like so:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

...would be of any benefit?

As I said, it works fine, but would this possibly make execution a bit faster? If there is no benefit, what is the purpose of the CommandType SqlCommand member?

Comment: There are a number of things in your code I would recommend changing. First as with any programming it is always a good idea to be explicit and setting the command type is one of them. However, in your example this is NOT a stored proc. You are using pass through sql to execute a procedure. If you were executing this as a procedure the command text would be the name of the procedure and your values would be parameters. Last but not least, you should avoid the sp_ prefix (or better yet, avoid prefixes altogether). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You know you're calling a stored procedure, and you're asking a community if there's any reason NOT to type 30 characters to formalize the fact that you're calling a stored procedure? Are you trying to save characters / improve productivity in the same way you're not using proper cmd.Parameters?

Comment: Also, you should really [use sql parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @SeanLange: As to the "sp_" prefix, there's nothing I can do about that. I am not the DBA and am not authorized to change those names. Besides, doing so would probably be catastrophic, as there are hundreds of them.

Comment: Understand having your hands tied on that but would be worth bringing forward so that can stop going forward.

Comment: Also modern software and tools really should make refactoring a cinch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: There are always unintended consequences. I don't see  the big deal about what they're named.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I guess you didn't read the post Sean linked to? Why pay a performance penalty for every single stored procedure call just to keep them named poorly?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Because renaming them would break a gob of software that would come out of the woodwork like wailihg banshees.

Comment: Yep, there will always be excuses. Of course you could consider giving those apps time to update using `sp_rename sp_badname bettername; create synonym sp_badname for bettername;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm talking about many apps written in VB and other languages that references those names; who knows how many there are? For some there might not even be source code available anymore.

Comment: Ok, and those can access the synonym just fine, but this would give you the opportunity to make this right for the applications you can still control.