# Pass multiple parameters into ExecuteQuery()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm currently trying to pass in multiple parameters into an ExecuteQuery() call that is executing a stored procedure. My stored procedure expects 3 parameters of the following types (bit, varchar, int). I attempted to pass the parameters in like this but they seem to just be ignored by the stored procedure and it returns all of the results instead of filtering the results based on the values I pass in. Oddly enough when I pass the values in through SSMS it returns the expected result.

```
string query = string.Format("EXEC {0}", storedProcName);
Context.ExecuteQuery(returnType, query, new object[]{false, "test", 0});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, what's "Context"? How do you connect to your database? ADO.NET? Entity Framework?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7542564/2893376) could help you.

Comment: @JCM I am connecting to my DB using ADO.NET.

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to do this without using the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects.