# Is this a good way to execute queries in a SQL Server database from c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the next code to run queries in the database in my system. :

```
public static DataSet execute_query(string query)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = DataAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.cn;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ds = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

1. Is this a secure or good way to run queries in the database from c#?
2. I have read about queries with parameters. How I can do this using parameters?

Comment: This is one the most common goals in web applications in C#, ever. It shouldn't be hard to find documentation to help you on your way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This question best fits to the [code review stack](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are not disposing the `SqlDataAdapter` instance

Comment: Why not use an ORM such as Entity Framework coupled with stored procedures. Using explicit SQL in your application not only ties it to a single DBMS but also ties you to a schema.

Comment: 1. Probably not if they are not parameterized. 2. `SqlCommand.Parameters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I see that raise flags.

1. Your unit of work and repository code are living in the same method. This limits transaction handling among other things. Meh - lots of concessions have been made with using DA code not implementing UOW / Repo. So it's not a requirement.
2. You have a public method accept text to use as query. just make sure to separate that from any sort of user or api or good ole [bobby drop tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) may come to visit. **(this answers your secure question - it is secure if it's seperated from the interfaces and your query is 'scrubbed' before coming in)**
3. DataSets - im not a fan, IMO they are very bloaty. I generally use a `DataReader`, populate `IList<>` and call it a day. But by all means, use the DataSets (or DataTables) if you like.
4. No use of a `using` statement. You should dispose of objects implementing `IDisposable`, the using statement is an easy way to to this. Had you separated the UnitOfWork from the Repository then I wouldn't mention this - as the UnitOfWork would be disposed of elsewhere.

To use parameters make a `SqlCommand` object from your connection and query. In that object you can add parameters to the `Parameters` collection.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paramname", paramvalue);
```

Feed that to the `DataAdapter`
Good luck!