# Input on a stored sql procedure using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In sql I normally execute my procedure using

```
exec dbo.usp_FCS 'TIMV','serial'
```

And I tried something somewhat the same in c# but it seems I got this wrong

```
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password="))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_FCS_GetUnitInfo_Takaya" + "'" + MachineName + " ','serial' " , connection))
                {
                        try
                    {
                           
                            connection.Open();
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    }

                        catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        label6.Visible = true;
                        label6.Text = string.Format("Failed to Access Database!\r\n\r\nError: {0}", ex.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

My question is,how can I give those 2 inputs 'TIMV' and 'serial' of my stored procedure using c#?

#### Edit:

I tried something like this:

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_FCS_GetUnitInfo_Takaya"  , connection))
                {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MachineName;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "serial";
                        try
                    {    my code...
```

And it is still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct way to add a parameter to an SqlCommand is through the Add method that allows you to specify the datatype of the parameter and, in case of strings and decimals, the size and the precision of these values. In that way the Database Engine Optimizer can store your query for reuse and be a  lot faster the second time you call it. In your case I would write

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = MachineName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@serial", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "serial";
```

This assumes that your stored procedure receives two parameters named **EXACTLY** *@mname* and *@serial*, the type of the parameters is NVarChar and the length expected is 20 char. To give a more precise answer we need to see at least the first lines of the sp.

In your code above also the execution of the command is missing. Just creating the command does nothing until you execute it. Given the presence of an SqlDataAdapter I think you want to fill a DataSet or a DataTable and use this object as DataSource of your grid. Something like this

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
yourDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

And if this is an ASP.NET app, also the DataBind call

```
yourDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I must ask why did this work?I mean i just added a data grid and filled the grid and somehow it worked? what gives?

Comment: The important points are: Exact datatype,size and name for the parameters. The CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure is fundamentale otherwise the CommandText is interpreted as query (select, update...) Of course filling the DataTable (da.Fill(dt)) is mandatory to show anything on the grid

Comment: Let me explain what I have.I did not use your example,I used `AddWithValue`(I know its not ok but I'm trying to prove a point) .I have 2 procedures If i try to run the second one without running the first one the second one will trow an error.I tried to make it work every way possible, to add the parameters and nothing worked until I used the DataTable and I can't understand why?

Comment: Uhm, difficult to say without seeing the new code. I suggest to post a new question with details about this problem. So many more people could see your problem and try to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You use the [`Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of the `SqlCommand` class to send parameters to a stored procedure.

Suppose your parameter names are `@p1` and `@p2` (Please, for your sake, don't use names like this ever) - your c# code would look like this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_FCS_GetUnitInfo_Takaya", connection))
{
    cmd..CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MachineName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@21", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "serial";

    try
    {
       // rest of your code goes here....
```

Note: use the [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) value that fits the parameters data type.

Comment: Do I also need to add any assembly reference?

Comment: Error CS1061 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet("dts");
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
          ("Data Source=;Initial  Catalog=;User ID=;Password="))
        {
            try
            {
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new  SqlCommand("usp_FCS_GetUnitInfo_Takaya",conn);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", MachineName);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "serial");
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                label6.Visible = true;
                label6.Text = string.Format
              ("Failed to Access  Database!\r\n\r\nError: {0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)