# Incorrect syntax near 'achternaam'

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to insert a new row into a SQL Server table from a Winforms application. As far as I know my query is correct but Visual Studio keeps returning an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'achternaam'

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

```
public void UpdateGegevens(int id, string voornaam, string achternaam, string functie, DateTime geboortedatum, decimal uurloon)
{
if (ReturnFirstTime(id) == true)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_Gegevens (Id, voornaam, achternaam, geboortedatum, functie, uurloon) VALUES (@Id, @vn, @an, @gb, @f, @ul);";

            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@vn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = voornaam;
            command.Parameters.Add("@an", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = achternaam;
            command.Parameters.Add("@f", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = functie;
            command.Parameters.Add("@gb", SqlDbType.Date).Value = geboortedatum;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ul", SqlDbType.Money).Value = uurloon;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = con;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_Gegevens SET voornaam=@vn achternaam=@an geboortedatum=@gb funtie=@f uurloon=@ul WHERE Id = @Id;";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vn", voornaam);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@an", achternaam);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gb", geboortedatum);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", functie);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ul", uurloon);
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Here is a specification of `tbl_Gegevens`:

```
create table [dbo].[tbl_Gegevens] (
   [Id] int not null
 , [voornaam] nvarchar(50) null
 , [achternaam] nvarchar(50) null
 , [geboortedatum] date null
 , [functie] nvarchar(50) null
 , [uurloon] smallmoney null
 , primary key clustered ([Id] asc)
 );
```

I think my dbms is ADO.Net.

This is the way i'm passing the info to the method:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbName.Text != "" && tbSurname.Text != "" && tbFunction.Text
            != "" && dtpBirthdate.Value != date && nudSalary.Value != 0)
            {
                Database1.SetFirstTime(ID);
                Database1.UpdateGegevens(ID, tbName.Text, tbSurname.Text, tbFunction.Text, dtpBirthdate.Value, nudSalary.Value);
                this.Hide();
                frmMain fm = new frmMain(ID);
                fm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vul alle velden in!");
            }
        }
```

This is the query i use to get my id:

```
    public int ReturnLoginID(string username, string password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Login where UserName=@username and Password=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        int ID = 9999;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
        con.Close();
        return ID;
    }
```

Comment: Which DBMS?  Also need table definition of `tbl_Gegevens`...

Comment: Here is a specification of tbl_Gegevens:

    

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Gegevens] (
        [Id]            INT           NOT NULL,
        [voornaam]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [achternaam]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [geboortedatum] DATE          NULL,
        [functie]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [uurloon]       SMALLMONEY    NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );



I think my dbms is ADO.Net.

Comment: I would have used `ExecuteNonQuery` for this db action. And I would have put square brackets around `Id`. And are you sure the `Id` is writable (i.e. not an identity specification)?

Comment: I don't believe this code throws that exception. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve],

Comment: I am going to try ExecuteNonQuery right now. Amazing that i didn't notice this as i know that i should only use ExecuteScalar for querys with multiple values returned.

Comment: Is ExecuteNonQuery make any difference ? Can you execute the query in managment studio and check it ?

Comment: @BasMolenaar - see my comment (2nd from top). Use Sql Server Management Studio OR use Sql Server Explorer in Visual Studio. Just be sure your database is the selected active database (using a drop down or type `use databasenamehere` in SSMS)

Comment: @CodeCaster - your right. I can only reproduce that exact error message if I omit the `,` between `voornaam` and `achternaam`. Seems the `INSERT` is probably omitting the `,` in the code and the OP omitted it from the question OR did not properly execute a rebuild when testing and is using an older compiled version of the app.

Comment: `I think my dbms is ADO.Net.` <= ado.net is a library used to communicate with database management systems (dbms). An example of a dbms is Sql Server (which is probably what you are using based on the types you are using).

Comment: @BasMolenaar I see this line _if (ReturnFirstTime(id) == true)_ Did you omit the UPDATE part from the code above and, by chance, the error comes from that part?

Comment: @Bas again, if this is your actual code, this is **not the code throwing that exception**. Probably there's an error in the SELECT query in frmMain. Or what Steve says.

Comment: @Bas Molenaar, maybe you should try something new: if you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you could try writing a stored procedure with parameters. Then you can [call that stored procedure from code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7542564/6936343) , as well as execute it by passing in the parameters using SSMS. It is better and cleaner to work that way!

Comment: And now we see the error. Missing a comma between ALL the fields in the SET list _....SET voornaam=@vn, achternaam=@an, ....., ....._

Comment: This is also why a stack trace is very important. If you can properly read an Exception then you can figure out the exact line number the exception occurred on. Also if you are debugging the code attached to Visual Studio it will even stop on the line where you call Execute... from the SqlCommand and then you can see the command text it was executing. Either way learn to use your debugger AND learn to read Exceptions (not just the Message property).

Comment: @Tony no, stored procedures for simple CRUD operations are a maintenance nightmare. Anyway that has been discussed to death already. Edit: nevermind, you had it under Steve's answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UPDATE part of your code there are no commas to separate the fields in the SET list

```
command.CommandText = @"UPDATE tbl_Gegevens SET voornaam=@vn,
                       achternaam=@an, geboortedatum=@gb, 
                       funtie=@f, uurloon=@ul WHERE Id = @Id;";
```

I think that this question could be used to underline the importance of using a debugger. This problem would be solved much sooner if you had stepped through your code using the debugger.

Comment: Nice find! (*with the whole `ReturnFirstTime(id) == true` in the code*)

Comment: This kind of drama could have been prevented by [using stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7542564/6936343)!

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf Stored Procedure are not the panacea of all evils. Using them for trivial tasks like these results in a maintenance nightmares if you are not wearing also the DBA hat.

Comment: Whenever I see code with SQL queries inline, I become wary, because either the programmer was lazy or in a hurry and did not want to refactor the code. A quickfix that will often cause misery on the long term.

Comment: Also I found another stupidity, I set the first time to false before I write the data for the first time.  So UPDATE was always used instead of INSERT on the first time.

Comment: @steve, you could also use EF for your DAL. Inline SQL is acceptable, as long you are not creating huge stringbuilder nightmares!

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf Thanks. As i am still learning i did not know of it's existance. I wil use that from now on. Dankjewel ;)

Comment: Generating Create, Read, Update, Delete StoredProcedures for tables is also available: [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=12) Why write trivial code, while you can generate it on the fly?