# Stored procedures and parameter in Login for C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have been working on a project and I am very new to C#. I have Login which is correct but it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Here is my code - can anybody help me out how to apply a stored procedure with parameters so it can be more secure?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(Cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where Username= '" + Username.Text + "' And " +
                    "Password='" + Password.Text+ "'", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Cuhome.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LblError.Text = "Invalid Username & Password";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't understand the concept of how to put together. i really appreciated your help.

Comment: Did you try researching on Google? Or you want us to do that for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx?m=1

Comment: It looks like you are creating an asp.net project.  If you create an MVC project instead, you get all of this functionality, I'm a standard and highly secure way, for free.  In VS create a new solution and choose mvc.

Comment: @Neil is correct - you should not be building this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a stored procedure - just use a **properly parametrized** query - that achieves the same goal of being "more secure":

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    // set up query - using PARAMETERS as you always should!
    // Also: you don't seem to need the *whole* row - all the columns of "Users" - so select just what you **really need**!
    string query = "Select UserId from Users where username = @username and password = @password;";

    // put both SqlConnection *AND* SqlCommand into "using" blocks
    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(Cs))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        // provide the parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Username.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Password.Text;

        // use an ExecuteScalar call to get the UserId from Users - and check if it exists
        con.Open();

        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        // if we get something back --> the user with this password exists --> redirect
        if (result != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Cuhome.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LblError.Text = "Invalid Username & Password";
        }
    }
}
```

But this code has a **second, even more horribly flaw**: you seem to be storing the **password** for your users **in PLAIN TEXT** in your database table! That's a ***MAJOR*** no-no for any secure site - do **NOT** EVER store passwords in plain text !! You need to **hash and salt** password, if you actually store them.

Comment: Adding that in addition to better security, parameterized queries eliminate the need to enclose literals (or not) depending on the type, eliminate the need to escape quotes within strings, avoid the need to format date string literals in a particular way, do not require decimal separators, improve performance by promoting execution plan cache reuse, and result in cleaner code that's easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 for strongly-typed parameters instead of [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: I really appreciate your help i tried to do this but couldn't figure out. Thank You so much.