# Using stored procedures with web service in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I am working in Xamarin Form ... I create web service ASMX and SQL Server Database, and it works properly. But when I replaced the query by stored procedures there is an error.

what I do :

First of all,

I create class its name `DBConnection.cs` for connection string

```
  public class DBConnection
    {
        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Data Source=...........;Initial Catalog=..........;User Id=......; Password=......;";
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, I create the stored procedure `Login`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login] (
   @UserNameLogin NCHAR (20), 
   @UserPasswordLogin NCHAR (30)
   )
AS
   SELECT * FROM [Us] WHERE UserName=@UserNameLogin AND UserPassword=@UserPasswordLogin
RETURN 0
```

Finally, I used the code-behind to connect

```
public Result Login(string UserName, string UserPassword)
       {

           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(new DBConnection().ConnectionString);

           /// Class for return bool vaulable 
           Result result = new Result();
           try
           {

               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Login", con);

               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserNameLogin", UserName);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPasswordLogin", UserPassword);
               com.Connection = con;
               if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                   con.Open();
               SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
               if (rd.HasRows)
               {
                   rd.Read();
                   result.ValidUser = true;
                   return result;
               }
```

Where is the problem that 
**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'Login' expects parameter '@UserNameLogin', which was not supplied.**

and how to fix it?  did I need configurationManager ? and if it yes how to write the correct code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't think that, I'm not using asp.net. My case is Xamarin Form 
X

Comment: You get that error when you pass a parameter that has a null value and there is no default on the stored procedure. Have you stepped through with the debugger to look at the value of `UserName`?

Comment: Taking a closer look it shouldn't work at all because you haven't set the `CommandType` to stored procedure. Is that really the exact code you are executing?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xamarin, this is purely a c#/sql issue.  The web service doesn't know what kind of client is calling it

Comment: And as usual, let's add [don't use addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify `com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: That's only part of the problem, you would not get the reported error if the command tried to execute that as CommandType.Text which is the default.