# Procedure or function 'usp_GetVideoSelections' expects parameter '@UserID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to figure out how to resolve this error? The bolded part is where the error shows in the browser message.

I have that parameter in the stored procedure and I see it here so what am I missing?

```
Create procedure [Web].[usp_GetVideoSelections] (
    @UserID varchar(20)
)
AS
Select
UserID, CameraName
from
    Web.VideoPortalSelections
where UserID = @UserID
```

```
using (DatabaseConnection db = Shared.GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                using (StoredProcedure usp = new StoredProcedure(Shared.ProjectName, "Web.usp_GetVideoSelections"))
                {
                    usp.Parameters["@UserID"] = UserID;
                    usp.Parameters["@CameraName"] = CameraName;
                    **using (SqlDataReader reader = usp.ReadData(db))**
                    

                    do
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())

                                LoadVideoSelections(reader["CAMERANAME"].ToString().Trim());


                        }
                        while (reader.NextResult()
                        );
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is `StoredProcedure`?  Why not just use regular ADO.NET?

Comment: The error is in your database call, so it's not a SQL question, but your programming language's question. Please, add tags of your programming language and library/module

Comment: StoredProcedure use is a business rule here. I did add the C# and ASP.Net tags but they didn't save for some reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is you have not specified `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Nor does your procedure have a **parameter** named @CameraName

Comment: Is `UserID` equal to `null`?

Comment: @astentx Thanks but we don't use that format anymore.

Comment: @Charlieface, yeah that's not the issue but still working through it. thanks

Comment: @SMor, yes I know. The database admin said it's not needed in the sp.

Comment: You are trying to pass in two parameters when the stored procedure is only expecting one.  Create procedure [Web].[usp_GetVideoSelections] (
    @UserID varchar(20)
)