# Stored Procedure "Parameter not supplied"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I posted this with ASP.NET specific tags, but I think that was asking too broad a question, so I'm reposting the SQL part here more specifically. I have two ways of calling a procedure with output using T-SQL. The first is working fine with expected return values:

```
declare @p5 int
execute dbo.aspCreateQuote @customerID=13,@itemList='text goes here',@quoteID =@p5 output;
select @p5
```

The second is called using sp_executesql and does not work:

```
declare @p5 int
set @p5=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'psa.dbo.aspCreateQuote',N'@customerID int,@itemList varchar(1000),@quoteID int output'
,@customerID=13
,@itemList='[xml block of text goes here]',
@quoteID=@p5 output
select @p5
go
```

It gives the error that the procedure:

> expects parameter '@customerID', which was not supplied.

But why would there be any difference between the two calls? The second script is generated by an ASP.NET web app.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't inderstand the need for dynamic SQL here, there is nothing dynamic; think about what is going on in the context of the SQL being executed by sp_executesql - you are invoking aspCreateQuote and not passing it any parameters, hence the error.

Comment: @Stu - they probably aren't calling `sp_executesql` themselves. That is how a parameterised query from `ADO.NET` with command type text will show up

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks makes sense, presumably the appropriate ado *CommandType* fixes the syntax.

Comment: yep - because then it will just call the `aspCreateQuote ` stored proc directly and pass the params to that

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 2):

The second one passes the parameters into `sys.sp_executesql` but then they never get used inside there and passed to the call to `aspCreateQuote` .

For that to happen the SQL Statement you are executing would need to be something like

`N'EXEC psa.dbo.aspCreateQuote @customerID, @itemList, @quoteID output'`

not just

`N'psa.dbo.aspCreateQuote'`

But probably you just forgot to set the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` in the web app anyway and so just need to fix that. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542564/73226) for some example syntax that sets the CommandType)